# HOW TO BUILD A FAVICON GENERATOR

Tags: python, node.js, web-applications, python-imaging-library, backend

I have been tasked and assigned a project to build a web application that can generate favicon of various sizes and color from a single uploaded image of format PNG, JPG ETC with HTML code as well. Please I need your help on how to go about it.

I will appreciate any clue or hint on how to start this project. For the backend: Python or NodeJS is good.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: There are very popular python library for image manipulation. A quick Google research will give you access to tons of documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Easy with **ImageMagick** see https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#favicon

Comment: https://replit.com/@Eddyah5/Picture-manipulation-PILLOW#main.py Also I'd like to be able to check for different file extensions and accept them while rejecting anything outside of it. Example: "JPG", "JPEG", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "PNG", "bmp", "BMP", "gif", "GIF", "tiff", "TIFF", "webp", "WEBP" Plus to be able to download the final file .ICO file as a Zip file. Thanks @Daweo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? Generating images and exporting to various formats is very easy here. You should be able to get up and running within minutes after googling some basic tutorials

Comment: https://replit.com/@Eddyah5/Picture-manipulation-PILLOW#main.py Also I'd like to be able to check for different file extensions and accept them while rejecting anything outside of it. Example: "JPG", "JPEG", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "PNG", "bmp", "BMP", "gif", "GIF", "tiff", "TIFF", "webp", "WEBP" Plus to be able to download the final file .ICO file as a Zip file. Thanks @BigCodeMan